# Figuring the cubic polynomial $f(x)$ given two of its values, a local minimizers and a local maximizer

Tags: calculus, functions

Here is the given information in my question,

So, what my question inform is that there is a cubic polynomial function (i.e $f(x)$) which has **local** maxima at $x=-1$. While that for $f'(x)$, it's local minima lies at $x=1$.

Also it is given that $f(-1)=10$ and $f(0)=5$

So now there are two questions based on this information. Question 1 says

> **1.** Find $f(1)$?

while question 2 asks

> **2.** The distance between the two horizontal tangents is?

In first question, I managed to solve the question on the basis of several assumptions about which I myself is not sure. I think figuring the first questions would easily give me the result of second questions (as I'd be having the $f(x)$).

So here I am answering my own question and please help me out that whether my assumptions are valid or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the approach that I'd made in this question is a bit lengthy, hence I'd write only it's procedure here.

So what I firstly assumed that the second derivative (i.e $f''(x)$) of the function is

$$f''(x)=a(x-1)$$

I made this assumption from the information that says local minima of $f'(x)$ is at $x=1$.

And further integrating $f''(x)$ to $f'(x)$,

$$f'(x)=a(x^2/2-x)+b$$

from which I got the relation between $a$ and $b$ from $f'(-1)=0$ (as given in the question that $f(x)$ is having local maxima at $x=-1$)

What I got from this was, $b=\frac{-3a}{2}$.

While that from $f(-1)=0$ I was with another relation and finally I got the value of $a=6$ and $b=-9$

And finally from $f(0)=5$ and integrating it further to $f(x)$ I got,

$$f(x)=x^3-3x^2-9x+5$$

from where I easily got that $f(1)$ which was, $f(1)=-6$

Comment: Replaced $\phi \rightarrow a$ and $\alpha \rightarrow b$.

Comment: It looks fine to me. If you start with $f\left(x\right)=ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d$
then you find the equations $d=5$, $-a+b-c+d=10$, $3a-2b+c=0$ and $6a+2b=0$.
This leads to the same result.

Comment: Actually this question was asked in my exam and during exam time I also used this same approach but getting those four equations in such limited time was very horrible. Hence after being unsuccessful in my exam I asked this to my Maths teacher and he told me to do this question by assuming $f''(x)$ instead of $f(x)$ which would lead me faster results. However I was still in a little doubt with this method, that's why I asked it here.

Comment: Well, I am glad you are relieved now.